# Sass compilation issue

Tags: reactjs, sass, compilation

I am using sass in react project and using the sass package from npm. The problem is that when I try to access a variable stored in another module which uses function stored in another module, it doesn't work.

But when I store the variable in the same file as the one I'm trying to access from,it works.

I have also tried to use live Sass compiler but it gives similar result.

Why does this happen? Is it only two modules that sass can map through for a style rule?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look my file structure and you just need to add all scss files in a root file with right order

[Example](https://github.com/devendra-kushwah/React-scss-standard/blob/master/src/scss/_core.scss)

Comment: If you need any more information I can connect with you and explain everything how it works

Comment: If My solution help full for you please accept It

Comment: I forgot to add I am using "@use" and "@forward"